# Incorporating a workflow Initiation Infopath form in Visual Studio 2010 for Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, sharepoint, infopath

I am having issues trying to implement a workflow that pops up a infopath form when the workflow is activated. I followed the [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/195348/SharePoint-2010-State-Machine-Workflows-with-Custo) tutorial which gives a great example on how to link forms to tasks, but I have not been able to find any examples that uses Infopath forms for initiation and associated forms.

My current workflow elements.xml file looks like this after running the tutorial:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Workflow
     Name="DocReview - DocReview"
     Description="My SharePoint Workflow"
     Id="fdfd5e60-2210-4f67-9883-085090181816"
     CodeBesideClass="DocReview.Workflow1.Workflow1"
     CodeBesideAssembly="$assemblyname$"
     TaskListContentTypeId="0x01080100C9C9515DE4E24001905074F980F93160">
    <Categories/>
    <AssociationData>
      <Data></Data>
    </AssociationData>
    <MetaData>
      <AssociationCategories>List</AssociationCategories>
        <Task0_FormURN>urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:StartDocumentReview:-myXSD-2012-03-19T05-38-09</Task0_FormURN>
      <StatusPageUrl>_layouts/WrkStat.aspx</StatusPageUrl>
    </MetaData>
  </Workflow>
</Elements>
```

I tried adding a the Instantiation_FormURN and Association_FormURN elements in the elements.xml file using the same form but still cannot pop up the form on workflow activation. What m I missing?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, the workflow element requires the following attribute InstantiationURL="_layouts/IniWrkflIP.aspx". This works in conjunction with the Instantiation_FormURN element.

Checkout [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms563325%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Is complicated to make it work, but if you follow this article from start to finish you will.
http://spblog.net/post/2012/03/07/Creating-InfoPath-association-%28or-instantiation%29-form-for-SharePoint-2010-Visual-Studio-workflow.aspx